# Changing variables with a discrete measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have a sum over a finite set $X$ composed of $q$s, which are continuous variables :

$$ I = \sum_{q \in X} f(q) \, , $$

that I know I can rewrite in terms of a discrete measure

$$I = \int_X d\mu(q) f(q) \, . $$

Nothing really changed up to now. However, my objective in writing this sum as an integral is in exploiting its parameterization as a function of a continuous variable $p$, emerging from considering $q$ (which is continuous) as a function of $p$:

$$q = q(p) \Rightarrow dq = \left\vert \frac{dq(p)}{dp} \right\vert dp \, , $$

so that $I$ is brought to

$$I = \sum_{q \in X} f(q) \longmapsto \int_X d\mu(q) f(q) \longmapsto \int_\mathbb{R} dp \left\vert \frac{dq(p)}{dp} \right\vert f(q(p)) \, .$$

Is this allowed? I know it works numerically (I am integrating over a continuous variable and yes, the result is equivalent to performing the summation), but I would like to know if it's a mathematically sound procedure.

Comment: I have no idea why it would be allowed, as you switched from $d\mu$ to $dq$

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not allowed.
To do this you need to use $\frac{\text{d}\mu}{\text{d}p}$ instead of $\frac{\text{d}q}{\text{d}p}$:
$$\int_\mathbb{R} f \text{d}\mu=\int_\mathbb{R} f\cdot\frac{\text{d}\mu}{\text{d}p} \text{d} p$$
**But** $\mu$ is atomic it is not absolutely continuous wrt $\text{d}p$ (the Lebesgue measure) therefore $\frac{\text{d}\mu}{\text{d}p}$ does not exist.